# How to run input (x|grep y) in command

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, variable, read

lets say when I execute command and then grep it for a specific output.

for example: **man cat|grep "Written"**

This gives the name of the authors.

My problem is I want to do this via read.

here is an example of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read variable #lets say input is: man cat|grep "Written"

$variable
```

It does not seem to work. I need this to work as I am doing a larger script and this part got me stuck. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: `var=$(man cat | grep 'Written')` later you use it like: `"$var"` (don't forget double quotes to avoid word splitting).

Comment: "It does not seem to work" -- exactly how are you invoking your script? What actually happens? How does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: But, before you use ``eval`` (or ``bash -c``),  think hard about why you want to do this, or why you believe that you need to.